# Trying to connect rails app to trello APi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, access-token, trello

I am trying to connect my rails app to the trello API. I have asked for tokens and secrets at 
https://trello.com/app-key
I have installed the ruby gem 'ruby-trello' in my gemfile.

I need to generate a trello card with on submit of my contact form with the email submitted, the message's object and the message content. This is my create method in contact_controller.rb

```
def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:alert] = "Votre message a bien été envoyé à l'équipe TennisMatch, nous vous contacterons dans les plus brefs délais !"

        Trello.configure do |config|
          config.developer_public_key = ENV['PUBLIC_TRELLO_KEY']
          config.member_token = ENV['MEMBER_TRELLO_TOKEN']
        end
        me = Trello::Member.find("david_geismar")

      # find first board
      board = me.boards.first
      puts board.name
      # puts "Lists: #{board.lists.map {|x| x.name}.join(', ')}"
      # puts "Members: #{board.members.map {|x| x.full_name}.join(', ')}"
      board.cards.each do |card|
            puts "fu"
            # puts "-- Actions: #{card.actions.nil? ? 0 : card.actions.count}"
            # puts "-- Members: #{card.members.count}"
            # puts "-- Labels: #{card.labels.count}"
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

my application.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
      PUBLIC_TRELLO_KEY: "******"
      MEMBER_TRELLO_TOKEN: "******"
```

But everytime I am submitting my contact form I get the error :
invalid token

here's the actual log:

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
E, [2015-06-17T01:47:19.732876 #11385] ERROR -- : [401 GET https://api.trello.com/1/members/david_geismar]: invalid token

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 475ms

Trello::Error - invalid token
:
  ruby-trello (1.2.1) lib/trello/client.rb:99:in `invoke_verb'
  ruby-trello (1.2.1) lib/trello/client.rb:19:in`get'
  ruby-trello (1.2.1) lib/trello/client.rb:44:in `find'
  ruby-trello (1.2.1) lib/trello/member.rb:33:in`find'
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:14:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in`call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:219:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in`block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in`process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in`block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in`serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in`call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in`protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in`handle_request'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in`block in run'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'

Comment: Just to confirm - are you using Figaro gem, or similar, to automatically add the `application.yml` to your `env`?

Answer (score 3):

You might not be using the correct member token.

The 'secret' displayed on your https://trello.com/app-key page is not a member token.

You can obtain a member token by authorizing your app in a browser and copying the returned string. Use the following URL:

https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=YOUR_API_KEY&scope=read%2Cwrite&name=APP_NAME&expiration=never&response_type=token

- key = your developer API key
- scope = `read,write` to give you full access
- name = app name that appears in the authorization dialog, seems arbitrary
- expiration = `never` so that you don't need to keep renewing, default is 30 days
- response_type = `token` string that can be copied to your Rails config

The 'secret' is not used here at all. It seems to be only used for the oAuth method of authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables placed in `application.yml` are not automatically populated in your Rails environment.  You might want to take a look at the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem, which makes this super easy IMO.  Essentially, you can place your environment variables in a top level file called `.env` and the gem handles getting them installed in your environment.

Otherwise, you can add a bit of code in an initializer to read these into your environment.

Comment: I created a trello.rb file in initializers where I added the following:
`require 'trello'

Trello.configure do |config|
  config.developer_public_key = ENV['PUBLIC_TRELLO_KEY']
  config.member_token = ENV['MEMBER_TRELLO_TOKEN']
end
`
I still get the invalid token error though

Comment: No the issue with that the `ENV` variables are not getting loaded as expected.  You can confirm this in the console.  You would need code to load them from the .yml file or as I mentioned use a method like the dotenv gem to manage this for you.

Comment: I think they are correctly loaded as when I run the console and writte ENV['MEMBER_TRELLO_TOKEN'] or ENV['PUBLIC_TRELLO_KEY'], it does return the correct string

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  When you moved the config setup to a separate initializer, did you restart your rails server?  If you are familiar with `byebug` or another debugger (or just use `puts`), you can confirm whether the env variables seem to be loaded correctly inside the scope of your application.

Comment: Yes the environment variables are successfully loaded. I still get the error

Comment: Can you update your OP with a chunk of your actual log including the error so we see exact error code, line number, stack trace etc?

Comment: And it is failing on `me = Trello::Member.find("david_geismar")`?  You might want to start over and get a new key.  You can always set up config and do member find in the console to rule out your application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you load your `application.yml` ?

It is not loaded by default, you must add:

```
ENV.update YAML.load_file('config/application.yml')[Rails.env] rescue {}
```

to `config/application.rb`